# winRT catel example fails to run

Tags: mvvm, windows-runtime, catel

I've faced with problem while trying to run catel WinRt example. When I try to debug Catel.Examples.WinRT.Advanced VS 2012 throw exception

`Failed to create the delegate. Probably the wrong type of EventArgs is used and does not match the EventHandler<TEventArgs>`

What is wrong?

My config: win8,vs 2012, catel 3.6

Comment: We will investigate this. I created an issue for you. Will report back when fixed.

https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both issues are fixed. It was an issue with the WeakEventListener for WinRT. Please try the latest nightly build via nuget and all should work fine again.

You can find the nuget packages at http://nuget.org/packages?q=catel&prerelease=true&sortOrder=relevance

Comment: Thank you for such fast response, Geert. Usually I use installer, but I'll try to use nuget package tomorrow. Thank you for your hard work. Catel is really amazing open source product with the best support I've ever seen.